# Working with Post miles and aerial imagery

Tags: qgis

As a highway design engineer most of the time we work with county routes and post miles.

For persons who don’t know what a post mile is it is basically a mile marker number on the highway of where you are. These numbers increase from south to north and west to east.

For example, I would have something like this Mendocino 20 PM 7.5 – 14.5 with this, I would like to know if qgis can search for me an aerial imagery within the area.

I am not good in writing programs so something more automatic maybe with a plugin that has been made already would be great.

Comment: I think you should explain the reference number a bit more. Where is the origin, what part indicates the street, do you have all lat/lon coordinates of the street, or lat/lon coordinates of post markers? Are you looking for a suitable aerial image bounding box around the marker?

Comment: First of I am not talking about streets I am talking about highways which is a big difference. The following link will explain to you more about the reference no. and what is a post mile https://postmile.dot.ca.gov/PMQT/PostmileQueryTool.html. Yes I want a suitable aerial imagery within the marker area.